# Change of variable with non bijective function

Tags: distributions, probability

I have a logistic regression model: $softmax(WX)$ where $W$ is my parameter matrix and $X$ is my input. I want a density function over the outputs of that model.

Say I know that my $X$ are distributed according to some density $p$. From the [change of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) I know that the density of the outputs will be something like $p'(x) = p(x) det|J^{-1}|$ where $J = \frac{\partial{softmax(WX)}}{\partial{X}}$.

However, this holds only for a bijective function $softmax(WX)$.

What can I do if this is not the case - especially if $W$ is not square?

Comment: divide the domain of your non-bijective function into parts where the function is bijective and then apply change of variables. This might work.

Answer (score 3):

The generalization of the change of variable formula to the non-bijective case is generally hard to write out explicitly, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables
which essentially formalizes mpiktas's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I found this article

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities

excellent!

Comment: +1 I have been looking for the $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ case.